# blocked recv socket udp dgram

Tags: python, сокет

И так. Имеется сервер и клиент. Клиент знает адрес сервера основанного на UDP dgram и отправляет на сервер пакеты. Но странное дело. Пакеты вроде как уходят, но сервер их не читает. То есть, в блоке recv он не видит сообщений до тех пор, пока не будет отправлен взаимный пакет обратно клиенту (заранее зная его адрес). И только потом он начинает видеть сообщения от клиента. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем же проблема? (не использую броадкасты, так как и сервер и клиент находяться на расстоянии).

Comment: А проги в одной сети?

Comment: На момент тестирования да. Рассчет ведется на работу вне единой сети. Строго с серыми ip адресами.

Answer (score 0):

Это было все из-за NAT. Если вы заинтересованы в этой теме, вы можете узнать, как обойти NAT. Так например, можно использовать способ которым пользуется Скайп.